# Number of functions $f : \{1, 2, ..., n\} → \{1, 2, ..., n + 2\}$ satisfying $f (x) < f (y)$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let n be a positive integer. What is the number of functions $f : \{1, 2, ..., n\} → \{1, 2, ..., n + 2\}$ satisfying $f (x) < f (y)$ for every $x, y ∈ \{1, 2, ..., n\}$ such that $x < y$?

I've had similar examples in the past but I can't figure out the general procedure. I know that $|A| = n$ and $|B| = m$ then we have $n^m$ elements. But I can't tie it together. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Going from $f(k)$ to $f(k+1)$ you must increase by at least one.  Notice that you can't have too many of these steps be increases of two or more.  Recognize that you can break into cases based on the number of steps of size $2$ and the number of steps of size $3$.

Comment: For the general problem going from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ where $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$ you can approach similarly by using $g(1)=f(1)$ and $g(k)=f(k)-f(k-1)$ and use stars-and-bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the inequality is strict, we then have firstly that $f$ is in injective.

Now, when we map the numbers $\{ 1, \ldots n \}$ to $\{ 1, \ldots, n+2 \}$ we have to skip exactly $2$ numbers somewhere to preserve the order. We can choose which numbers these are from the $n+2$ in ${n+2}\choose{2}$ ways

Comment: Therefore, we always use a choose function to determine the number of ways? And why do we need to skip 2 numbers? To make it well define?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if you delete any two elements in $\{1,2,....,n+2\}$ you get the function you want. So...

Comment: +1: from [Review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1004436)

Comment: How it end there?

Comment: Someone flagged it.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Once you know the image of $f$, the function $f$ is uniquely determined. Now, in how many ways can you choose the image of $f$? ( it will be a subset with $n$ elements)